# WebSphere Liberty Shared Libraries on Eclipse

Tags: websphere-liberty

On Eclipse WAS Dev Tools Liberty plug-in we can specify shared-libraries for web applications, as we can see on the link below.

http://jaceklaskowski.pl/w/images/6/6a/Wlp85-scala-shared-library-project-properties-liberty-profile-shared-libraries.png

It would make a lot of sense to be able to do the same on EJB modules (or even on EAR level). Is there any way to do it on Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no way to do the same for EJB or EAR projects in Eclipse, but I agree this would make sense. You can submit a formal request here: https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/help/submit-rfe/

WAS dev forums: https://www.ibmdw.net/answers/?community=wasdev